# Count total orders and total products for each customer

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have 3 tables:

- customers (CustomerID)
- orders (OrderID, CustomerID)
- orders_products (OrderID, ProductID)

I need to select each customer with their total orders and total number of products ordered by them.

To count total orders by each customer, the query is:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, COUNT(o.OrderID) AS TotalOrders 
FROM customers AS c 
INNER JOIN orders AS o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID 
GROUP BY o.CustomerID 
ORDER BY TotalOrders DESC
```

But how to count total number of products ordered by each customer?

I want something like below:

| CustomerID | TotalOrders | TotalProducts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 12 |
| 2 | 3 | 8 |

**Question UPDATED with Sample Data:**

I have updated my question with sample data of my three tables. The output of query suggested by some STO users here is also given below.

**customers:**

| RowID | CustomerID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

**orders:**

| RowID | OrderID | CustomerID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 1 |
| 2 | 102 | 1 |
| 3 | 103 | 2 |
| 4 | 104 | 1 |

**orders_products:**

| RowID | OrderID | ProductID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 1 |
| 2 | 101 | 2 |
| 3 | 102 | 1 |
| 4 | 103 | 1 |
| 5 | 104 | 1 |

**Query:**

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, COUNT(o.OrderID) AS TotalOrders, COUNT(op.ProductID) AS TotalProducts 
FROM customers AS c INNER JOIN orders AS o 
ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN orders_products AS op 
ON o.OrderID = op.OrderID 
GROUP BY c.CustomerID 
ORDER BY TotalOrders DESC, TotalProducts DESC
```

**Output (Incorrect):**

| CustomerID | TotalOrders | TotalProducts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |

You can see that customer with ID 1 has placed 3 orders and 5 products purchased under these orders. But query gives 4 total orders and also 4 total products for him. That's wrong!

**Expected Output (Correct):**

| CustomerID | TotalOrders | TotalProducts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: GROUP BY in subqueries _before_ joining.

Comment: @jarlh Can you please provide me a sample query?

Comment: @jarlh People are suggesting me 3 JOINs but I know that won't work. I commented there. I think it must be solved by one JOIN with a subquery.

Comment: Can 1 order have more than 1 customer?

Comment: @VikramDhanwani what do you mean?

Comment: I mean can order with ID = 1 can have 2 or more customer IDs associated with it?

Comment: @VikramDhanwani Dude you are asking absolutely wrong question here. How can it even be possible? Does it happen on Flipkart or Amazon? One unique order ID is always linked to a specific customer and not to any other customer. Not sure why did you ask so?

Comment: The request you're asking is flawed as long as your requirements do not match their application to the input tables to get the expected output you have presented here. Moreover you shouldn't upload data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Spend some time and effort to sanitize your post in order to make it clear and sound. Here's some [extra tips](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) on how to write a good SQL post.

Comment: lemon, I updated my question again and rectified my mistakes related to mysql data images. Can you please go through my question now? Btw, where were those answers gone which were suggested by some STO users here?

Comment: Please provide the table definitions along with the insert statements, so this can be replicated.

Comment: @Sachin Below in my case I changed orders table and it contains ProductID and CustomerID and it gives the correct result, hope to help you.

Answer (score 1):

we can calculate this by using joins,

step1: calculated number of products per each customer and named as x
step2: calculated number of orders per each customer and named as y
step3: do the self join considering x,y derived tables and select required
columns.      **input_tables:**
[image: Input Tables]

below is the script part:

```
select x.cust_id,no_of_orders,no_of_products 
from 
(
select o.cust_id ,count(p.order_id) as no_of_products  from Orders o
join products p 
on p.order_id = o.order_id group by o.cust_id
) as x ,
(
select o.cust_id ,count(o.order_id) as no_of_orders  from Orders o
join Customer c
on c.cust_id = o.cust_id group by o.cust_id
) as y 
where x.cust_id = y.cust_id
```

[image: results]

Answer (score 0):

First ProductID is a primary key should be unique.
Second i try with different types of JOIN :
INNER JOIN: Returns records that have matching values in both tables
LEFT JOIN: Returns all records from the left table, and the matched records from the right table
RIGHT JOIN: Returns all records from the right table, and the matched records from the left table
CROSS JOIN: Returns all records from both tables

But nothing there is a mistake on the relation between the table.

In my case I changed orders table and it contains ProductID and CustomerID and it gives the correct result,
hope to help you

```
-- create
CREATE TABLE customer (
  customerId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE orders (
  ordersId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  customerId INTEGER,
  productsId INTEGER,
  CONSTRAINT FK_CustomerOrder FOREIGN KEY (customerId)
    REFERENCES customer(customerId),

  CONSTRAINT FK_PersonProducts FOREIGN KEY (productsId)
    REFERENCES products(productsId)  
);

CREATE TABLE products (
  productsId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);

-- insert
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES (2);


INSERT INTO orders VALUES (101, 1, 10001);
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (102, 1, 10001);
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (103, 2, 10005);
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (104, 1, 10003);


INSERT INTO products VALUES (10001);
INSERT INTO products VALUES (10002);
INSERT INTO products VALUES (10003);
INSERT INTO products VALUES (10004);
INSERT INTO products VALUES (10005);

-- fetch 
SELECT c.customerId, 
       COUNT(o.ordersId) AS TotalOrders,
       COUNT(op.productsId) AS TotalProducts
FROM customer AS c 
INNER JOIN orders AS o ON c.customerId = o.customerId 
INNER JOIN products AS op ON o.productsId = op.productsId
GROUP BY c.customerId
```

Comment: Not working! Your query gives wrong count of TotalOrders. Actually it yields me the same count of TotalOrders as TotalProducts. I had already tried 3 JOINs before posting this question here.

Answer (score 0):

I have 1st calculated total number of products per order using the sub-query. Then, I'm join the tables of orders_products, orders, & customers to calculate the total orders & total products for each customer.

```
SELECT 
       cust.CustomerID, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT ord.OrderID) AS TotalOrders, 
       SUM(OrdPrd.TotalProducts) AS TotalProducts

FROM customers cust

JOIN orders ord ON cust.CustomerID = ord.CustomerID
JOIN (
     SELECT OrderID, COUNT(ProductID) AS TotalProducts
     FROM orders_products
     GROUP BY OrderID
) 
OrdPrd ON ord.OrderID = OrdPrd.OrderID

GROUP BY cust.CustomerID
ORDER BY TotalOrders DESC, TotalProducts DESC;
```